# calling an abstract method in a concrete method inside an abstract class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class, factory-pattern

I have below scenario where an abstract class has an abstract method of a class type and the abstract method has been called inside a concrete method of the same abstract class.

**Can someone explain the below concept of OOPS?** I am sorry if I am asking silly Q.

```
using FactoryPattern.PizzaProduct;

namespace FactoryPattern.PizzaStore
{
    public abstract class PizzaStore
    {
        public Pizza OrderPizza(PizzaType type)
        {
            var pizza = CreatePizza(type);
            pizza.Prepare();
            pizza.Bake(); 
            pizza.Cut();
            pizza.Box();
            return pizza;
        }
        protected abstract Pizza CreatePizza(PizzaType type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Template Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

This pattern allows children class to implement only the relevant bit of logic without the knowledge that is encapsulated in the parent class.

In your words, it allows every specific pizza store to define some characteristics of a pizza without knowing how the pizza must be prepared, baked, cutted, boxed.